# postgresql - max number from projected columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assuming a select statement returns

```
x,1,3,4,2,5,8,3
y,1,3,4,9,5,8,3
```

Is there a way to project the row with the max value in row?

I.e.

```
x,1,3,4,2,5,8,3,8
y,1,3,4,9,5,8,3,9
```

Comment: Are you confused about rows and columns?  What are the names of your columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `least()` and `greatest()`?

```
select . . . , greatest(col1, col2, col3, col4, . . . )
from t;
```

Comment: with your permission, a followup, is there a way to project the collumn index rather then the value?

Comment: @Y.S . . . You need to use a giant `case` expression or something similar.